# How to change date format vb.net 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I want to filter SQL-table between start date and end date, I used before string variable then I use `string.format` to make the format `mm/dd/yyyy`, I tried now in VB.net 2015 the following code:

```
Dim S as String
s=inputbox("Enter Start date")
S=string.format(S,"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

But it doesn't work, can somebody give me a solution?

Comment: What you need to do is parse the user-entered text into a [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). See the [DateTime.TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). (Incidentally, the prompt should explicitly state the format requested, like "Enter start date (mm/dd/yyyy)".)

Comment: Don't use an input box for user date input. Use a form with a datetimepicker control that allows them to enter the date in their own locale and returns a `Date` object from the `Value` property - no parsing required

Comment: The problem is quite possibly in your DB related code and/or how you are storing the date and/or filtering.  Actual `Date` Types dont have a format - just how they are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this for handling the input value, assuming you only need the date value as a formatted string, since your question is about formatting a date:

```
Dim S As String
S = InputBox("Enter Start date")
If IsDate(S) = True Then
   Dim d As Date = Date.Parse(S)
   S = d.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")
Else
   'Handle the non date input here
End If
```

But I think you should consider @Plutonix comment, since we don't know exactly how you are sending the date to perform the filtering, or how your table fields are defined.

Regards!